# Range-based for loop on vector that is a member variable

Tags: c++

C++11

What's the code to iterate, using range-based for loop, over a std::vector that is a member of a class? I I've tried a few versions of the following:

```
struct Thingy {
  typedef std::vector<int> V;

  V::iterator begin() {
      return ids.begin();
  }

  V::iterator end() {
      return ids.end();
  }

  private:
      V ids;
};

// This give error in VS2013
auto t = new Thingy; // std::make_unique()
for (auto& i: t) {
    // ...
}

// ERROR: error C3312: no callable 'begin' function found for type 'Thingy *'
// ERROR: error C3312: no callable 'end' function found for type 'Thingy *'
```

Comment: It works with a normal object, not a pointer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`t` is a `Thingy *`. You didn't define any functions for `Thingy *`, your functions are defined for `Thingy`.

So you have to write:

```
for (auto &i : *t)
```

Comment: Yeah, this is it. I wonder why the language doesn't automatically dereference the pointer when t is used bare. Oh well, thanks.

Comment: I'm quite glad the language doesn't automatically dereference pointers!

Comment: @Dess: If it did, there wouldn't be much point in references, would there?  :P

Answer (score 1):

You should use a "normal" object if you can:

```
Thingy t;
for (auto& i: t) {
    // ...
}
```

alternatively use `std::unique_ptr` and then *dereference* the pointer:

```
auto t = std::make_unique<Thingy>();
for (auto& i: (*t)) {
    // ...
}
```